# How to debug Checkout Subscribe Magento extension?

Tags: magento

I have installed magento Checkoutsubscribe extension which provides an option for users to subscribe to newsletter during the one page checkout process.

Installed fine, shows as installed but it doesn't do anything.

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this.

Can anyone provide any pointers as to how best to start testing each stage in the extension process?

Answer (score 0):

Issue lay with incompatibility with magento 1.7.
In the end developers produced a bug fixed version, sorry there isn't a more code based answer but thought it still worth sharing the solution.